# When Spring Batch reads and uses data persisted by JobRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I know that JobRepository is mandatory in any Spring Batch application and is used to store the meta data about running jobs and steps.

But are those *stored data* actually ever retrieved and used by Spring Batch? If yes, then when and what for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Spring Batch reads these meta-data and uses them extensively in many use cases. Here are some examples:

- When you run a job with a given set of parameters, it will check if there is a job instance already defined for the given parameters (`JobInstanceAlreadyExistsException`)
- When you run a job instance, it will check if there is no job execution already complete (`JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException`)
- When you run a job instance, it will first check if there is no job execution already running (`JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException`)
- When you re-run a failed job, it will retrieve the execution context in order to restart the job where it left off
- If you request a job execution to stop, it will check if the job execution exists (`NoSuchJobExecutionException`) and is currently running (`JobExecutionNotRunningException`).

Comment: Can you please give the links to documentation or quotes to prove the 1st and 4th points? I couldn't find it there..  
All of these usages seem to happen during the same runtime. What if the app is restarted.. which data from previous run will it retrieve from DB right after restart?

Comment: "Can you please give the links to documentation or quotes to prove the 1st and 4th points?"

For point 1: see https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/domain.html#jobinstance

For point 4: see https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/job.html#stoppingAJob and the javadoc of `JobOperator#stop`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/JobOperator.html#stop-long-

Comment: "What if the app is restarted.. which data from previous run will it retrieve from DB right after restart?"

This is point 3: the execution context is persisted in the database and retrieved in a restart scenario. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/schema-appendix.html#metaDataBatchJobExecutionContext